# jquery-addresspicker - limiting autocomplete hints to one country

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have a problem with jQuery UI widget for autocompleting an address:

https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker

I'm trying to limit autocomplete hints for one country only (or, at least, to prefer one country) - Poland.

**In example - I'm searching for "Kraków". [Cracow, Poland]**

I'm typing:
'Kra'
and there are such hints as:

- Krae, Tajlandia (Thailand)
- Kerang Airport (KRA), Kerang Wiktoria 3579, Australia

I have to type 'Krakó' to get a proper hint:

- Kraków, Polska (Poland)

I just don't need autocompleting with cities from Thailand, USA, France, etc. - i need cities from Poland.

Setting region (http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=pl) or address/bounds influences only on query results, not on autocomplete hints.

Could you give me any advices?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar problem - i resolved mine by using Google Places Autocomplete:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=pl#places_autocomplete

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'pl'}
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

It's not a great solution, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you have to filter the results in _geocode function
you iterate in result object in order to find type=="country" & shortname==your country code and you only take the one that met this condition

here is my modified function for france adresses, it is a bit dirty but it works

```
// Autocomplete source method: fill its suggests with google geocoder results
_geocode: function(request, response) {
var address = request.term, self = this;
this.geocoder.geocode({
'address': address + this.options.appendAddressString,
'region': this.options.regionBias
}, function(results, status) {
var fr_results= [];
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
results[i].label = results[i].formatted_address;
for (var j = 0; j<results[i].address_components.length; j++)
{

//console.log(results[i]);
if ((results[i].address_components[j].types[0] =="country") && (results[i].address_components[j].short_name =="FR"))
{
//console.log(results[i].address_components[j].short_name);
results[i].label = results[i].formatted_address;
//fr_results[i] = results[i];
fr_results.push(results[i]);
}
}
};
} 
//console.log(results);
//console.log(fr_results);
response(fr_results);
})
},
```

if anyone got a best way to do it, i take it :)

hf
dg